# How to alter data in relations field in laravel eloquent model after returning result?

Tags: laravel-eloquent-resource

I'm working with Laravel 5.6. And fetching data from database using Eloquent model. On that returned result set I found "relations" field as empty. But I need to alter this "relations" filed with some custom data. How should I do that?

My returned result:

[image]

In the picture, highlighted filed need to alter with some custom data.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, I solved the above problem myself. Solution like below:

```
$combinations_obj = (object) array("requested_quantity" => $product_combination->product_combination[0]->requested_quantity);
$combination_data->combinations[] = $combinations_obj;
$product_challan_infos->product_combination_list[] = $combination_data;
```